# How to add a git repo python library to my heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

Heroku generally has some good docs, but I found this one less than fully helpful:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

I am trying to use a library in my app: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance

I have some pip dependencies working just fine, but this is just a git repo. Should I just download the whole repo and push it in with my app or is there a cleaner way to add it?

The docs seems to suggest add this line: git+git://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance but it does not state where to add it. Is this a heroku command?

OR, is this a git command that I add somewhere in the git files?

Answer (score 0):

it is a pip command: `pip install git+git://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance`